# Type '() => { body: string; status: number; }' is not assignable to type svelte

Tags: json, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

trying to make a basic api endpoint of svelte using RequestHandler from index.json.ts file

```js
import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const get: RequestHandler = () => {
    return{
        body:'Hello from api.',
        status:200
    }
}
```

and getting errors:

> Type `() => { body: string; status: number; }` is not assignable to
> type `RequestHandler<Partial<Record<string, string>>, string | null>`.
>   Type `{ body: string; status: number; }` is not assignable to type
> `MaybePromise<Response>`.
>     Type `{ body: string; status: number; }` is missing the following properties from type `Response`: headers, ok, redirected, statusText,
> and 9 more. ts(2322)

tried making an endpoint accessible to the project yet keep getting
these errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I strongly type a SvelteKit Request Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71813466/how-do-i-strongly-type-a-sveltekit-request-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current versions of SvelteKit there are multiple issues here:

- Custom endpoints have to be in `+server.ts`/`js` files
- The name of the handler has to be all-caps
- The handler has to return a full `Response` object, as can be seen in the type error

So in a `+server.ts`:

```js
import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const GET: RequestHandler = () => {
    return new Response(
        'Hello from api.',
        { status: 200 }
    );
};
```